# My program wont read a 0 before the bookcase number in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that displays book names and their bookcase numbers.

However, I need to make sure there should be a `0` set for all the bookcase numbers that aren't a 3-digit number. For example, the output should show `2/056`, but instead it is showing me `2/56`.

Can anyone tell me how I can put a `0` before all the 2-digit numbers and not the 3-digit numbers? It should be done using `setfill()`.

```cpp
std::ostream& Book::write(std::ostream& ostr, bool onScreen) const
{
    if (onScreen)
    {
        if (*this)
        {
            ostr << m_BookTitle;
            ostr << setw(42 - strlen(m_BookTitle)) << setfill(' ');
            ostr << "| " << m_AuthorName;

            ostr << setw(27 - strlen(m_AuthorName)) << setfill(' ');

            ostr << "| " << m_ShelfNumber << "/" << m_BookcaseNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            ostr << "Invalid Book Record ................... | ........................ | .....";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (*this)
        {
            ostr << m_BookTitle << "," << m_AuthorName << "," << m_ShelfNumber << "/" << m_BookcaseNumber;
        }
        else {
            ;
        }
    }

    return ostr;
}
```

Comment: What is the `if (*this)` check for?

Comment: @selbie Yes, does that even compile?

Comment: From the context, it appears that he has an `operator bool` or other implicit conversion to a numeric or pointer type that is used to test whether the record is "valid".

Comment: DId you mean it won't _write_ a leading zero?

Answer (score 1):

Put `ostr << setw(3)<<setfill('0')` before you print the number that supposted to be 3 digit

Answer (score 1):

`ostr << setw(27 - strlen(m_AuthorName)) << setfill(' ');`

You *do* know about `setfill`, so why are you asking?

I wonder if you know what it's actually for?  You're using it to replicate a space and calculating the number of spaces based on the field length.  But that's insane, since you should **just set the width** you want `m_AuthorName` to be extended to. You appear to want the field justified to the left of a 27-character zone, with spaces filling the rest.

`ostr << setw(27) << left << m_AuthorName;`

is what you want here.

For the number, you want to **fill with `0` characters**.

Look at the examples [on the bottom of this reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

---

I don't see all the code, but I wonder why you call the C function `strlen` to get the length of a string.  Are you not using `std::string` to hold these values?